# ssl install from .crt - how do I get public and private from this file?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I was provided with a .crt file that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...etc.etc....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In my nginx settings I have a location for a public and private key files.

How do I generate those two files from this? Is that how it usually works?

Comment: Chances are your certificate contains only a public key.  Or at least, it should.  Your private key is probably stored in another file, often with an extension like .pem, .key, .ppk, etc, depending on how it was generated.

Comment: Our client just gave us that. If they bought it somewhere like godaddy should I assume they would also have another file that I'm missing? You can't generate the other file from a crt can you?

Comment: Nope, that's specifically designed to be computationally intractable.  It is possible that it's embedded in the certificate (though somewhat unlikely).  Consider consulting with your local cryptography or openssl guru.  In the absence of a guru, you might be able to find what you're looking for by googling around about openssl certificates.  Just in case your certificate has a private key embedded in it, DO NOT SHARE IT here or anywhere else.  Doing so could cause A LOT of trouble.

Comment: When you say you were "provided" with a .crt file, were there any other instructions or files included?